# "long" <i> - inconsistencies in the relationship between orthography and pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm wondering about the dual pronunciations of the letter /i/ in open syllables. Usually it has the realization [a͡ɪ], representing the regular outcome of long i after the great vowel shift, but sometimes it is [iː], as in "saline". Can anyone provide some theories on why this is?

(My theory is that, as spelling has remained the same since the pronunciation of the letter changed while English has continued to take in more and more foreign loan words, this is an imitation of the letter /i/'s pronunciation in most other languages, that is, a high front vowel. Or maybe it has something to do with stress patterns?)

I wasn't sure whether to post this here or in the linguistics stack exchange.

Comment: Good question. Even though it looks like the 'y's in them were pronounced nearly identically before the Great Vowel Shirt, *glorify* was taken to /ai/, but *charity* left as /i/. And some words, like [saline](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saline), are pronounced both ways.

Comment: It depends on what language the words comes from (half of English is not Germanic in origin) and how the pronunciation came through. This varies so much that algorithmically deriving pronunciations from spellings is not noticeably more effective than dictionary lookup, and it seems clear that many literate English speakers never learn or practice the rules for this reason. Hence they are generally incomplete, incorrect, or based on faulty parallels; at least since the standardization of English spelling.

Comment: It's not just the language; *glorify* and *charity* are both from Latin through Old French, and they're pronounced differently.

Comment: @Peter Shor: "glorify" and "charity" come from different vowels in French, though (as reflected in Middle-English spellings like "charitee"). The spelling in Modern English doesn't reflect that, but the pronunciation does.

Comment: @sumelic: While "glorify" and "charity" do come from different vowels in French, can you tell me how this affected their English pronunciation? Shakespeare rhymed *fortify* and *memory*. Why didn't he notice that these had different vowels?

Comment: @Peter Shor: Poetry isn't necessarily a reliable guide to pronunciation in matters like this. There is such a thing as eye-rhyme. Even if the vowels were merged for Shakespeare, they might not have been for others; wasn't the boil-bile merger also common in his time?

Comment: Shakespeare rhymed *memory* with *die*, *sky*, *masonry, fortify, eternity,* rhymed *qualify* with *lie*, and rhymed *eye* with *lie* and *majesty*. I think it's pretty clear that these all ended with (at least nearly) the same vowel.

Comment: This isn't really a matter of open vs. closed syllables. All the i’s in _inner, illiterate, inimical_ are phonetically in open syllables, and homorganic lengthening in EME means there are quite a few cases of diphthongal i’s in closed syllables: _wild, behind, climb_, etc.

Comment: @PeterShor Also *grove*, *love*, *prove*.  It is of course possible (if not likely) that some of those words were pronounced differently by different people in Shakespeare's day.  Did "fire" and "messiah" rhyme in Tim Rice's day?  The answer is for some people "yes" and for others "no."

Answer (score 1):

While the patterns of English orthography are complex, the most likely factor here is indeed the influence of other languages, in particular, French, where orthographic "i" = [i] and "-ine" = [in]. However, the distribution in English of this pronunciation of "-ine" is somewhat irregular, and some words have /ɪn/ or /aɪn/ or even multiple attested pronunciations.